# html table with bootstrap textfield

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I need to add textfield in html table using bootstrap, but when using the bootstrap class in html table cell teh textfield is too small.
In the following code example the problem is in textfield id="Winvnetv".

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<tr>
  <form id="formSuppliestrn" method="post" class="form-horizontal" >
     <td>
        <input type="text" name="Wsupplyid" id="Wsupplyid" >
     </td>
     <td><input type="text" name="Wsupplydesc" id="Wsupplydesc"></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="Wquantity" id="Wquantity"></td>
     <td>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Ποσό τιμολογίου</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                 <span class="input-group-addon">€</span>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Winvnetv" id="Winvnetv"/>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </td>
     <td>
        <input type="text" name="Wtotv" id="Wtotv">
     </td>
     <td> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="trnadd">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
        </button>
     </td>
  </form>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `input-lg` or `input-sm` class to the textbox. It will increase its size.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="Winvnetv" id="Winvnetv"/>
```